# Execution failed for task ':react-native-android-location-enabler:generateDebugRFile'

Tags: android, react-native, npm

WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.5.3.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

> Task :react-native-android-location-enabler:generateDebugRFile FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
10 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 8 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-android-location-enabler:generateDebugRFile'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-android-location-enabler:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform react-native-0.63.2.aar (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.63.2) to match attributes {artifactType=android-symbol-with-package-name, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: D:\react\reactNative\GeoWheelDriver-master\node_modules\react-native\android\com\facebook\react\react-native\0.63.2\react-native-0.63.2.aar.
> > Failed to transform 'D:\react\reactNative\GeoWheelDriver-master\node_modules\react-native\android\com\facebook\react\react-native\0.63.2\react-native-0.63.2.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: invalid entry size (expected 939924 but got 939159 bytes). (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

Answer (score 1):

Try run `yarn jetify`

To migrate them to AndroidX? I really don't know. ๕๕๕

Answer (score 1):

add this code to all projects { in android/build.gradle

```
  def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a try with the below commands that might help you to resolve your issue with the react-native-android-location-enabler.

- **open Terminal**
- **cd android**
- **./gradlew clean**
- **./graldew assembleRelease**

The above commands will perform clean functionality for your Gradle and create a release build for you.

**UPDATE**

Try to remove your node_modules and install again.

- **Open Terminal**
- **rm -rf node_modules**
- **rm -rf yarn-lock.json**
- **yarn install**

If you are using npm as a package kindly use the required commands.

Comment: I have updated my answer please have a try with the new update